# Do incoherent sources of waves mean that the frequency of the sources are different?

Tags: waves

I studied that coherent sources of waves are those sources that maintain a constant phase difference between the two waves as time passed and incoherent sources are ones that don't. Does this imply that coherent sources are those sources which has same frequency and incoherent sources are those sources which have different frequency? Can we define incoherent sources as those sources whose frequencies are different?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score -1):

No, If the two sources have a constant phase difference this doesn't imply that the waves have equal frequency, You actually need to additionally assume this.

The two sources are said to be *coherent* if their frequency and waveform are equivalent.

The sources which are not coherent are incoherent.

---

Edit: Note that, In general
$$\mathbf{E}_1(\mathbf{r},t)=\mathbf{E}_{01}\cos(\mathbf{k}_1\cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega_1 t+\epsilon_1)$$
$$\mathbf{E}_2(\mathbf{r},t)=\mathbf{E}_{02}\cos(\mathbf{k}_2\cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega_2 t+\epsilon_1)$$
Thus the phase difference
$$\delta =(\mathbf{k}_1\cdot \mathbf{r})-(\mathbf{k}_2\cdot \mathbf{r})+(\omega_1-\omega_2)t+\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2$$
Since at optical frequencies the fields oscillate at in excess of $10^{14}$ Hz, $\epsilon_i(t)$ are time dependent so For coherent sources one needs,
$$\omega_1=\omega_2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2=\text{constant}$$

Comment: I guess that is why " temporal" and " spatial" coherence come from

Comment: That's what refers to coherence, Coherence is a measure of the correlation between the waves or with itself. Naively, Between is what is said, temporal, and with itself is what refer to spatial.

Comment: I see. What does it mean to be in coherence with itself? Does this involve a source that changes its frequency? Also, btw I've never heard of coherence relating to wavelength at all.

Comment: @Sidarth You can ask a different question on this. The wavelength and frequency are related by $c=\lambda \nu$ so it doesn't matter. and I haven't talked about wavelength.

Comment: We know that phase difference, $Δ\phi= (k_{2}-k_{1})(x_{2}-x_{1})-(ω_{2}-ω_{1})t$. For $Δ\phi$ to be constant, we have to obviously eliminate $t$ which is time because time will obviously keep changing which will lead to constantly changing $Δ\phi$. In order to eliminate $t$, $ω_{2}-ω_{1}= 0$ which implies $ω_{2}=ω_{1}$ which implies the frequency of both the waves must be equal.

Comment: @RIPANBARUAH Please find the edit.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi, but aren't $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ the initial phases of the two waves? If they are the initial phases of the two waves, shouldn't they be time-independent as that was their initial phase which remains constant as it happened in the past and cannot be changed?

Comment: @Younh Kindaichi, also what is wrong in my derivation?

Comment: The initial phase is changing in the sense that that the wave-train that is emitted by the source has a constant phase only for $10^{-14}$ sec so your proof is valid for this sort of time. In this sense, $\epsilon$ is time-dependent or better to say random.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi, what do you mean by "their waveforms are equivalent"? What is "waveform"?